# I'm waiting for you ON/AT/IN the second floor?

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

what is the correct option when I want to sat that I'm waiting for someone ON / IN / AT second floor?

> a) I'm waiting for you **on** the second floor.
>
> b) I'm waiting for you **in** the second floor.
>
> c) I'm waiting for you **at** the second floor.

Comment: While the "second floor" is an entire area, a *floor* is what you stand on. So use a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm waiting for you (at the lift, in the hallway) on the second floor.

Note the article "the" before second floor.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "**ON** the floor", but here is the explanation:

Since we are stepping on the floor rather than inside ("in") the floor itself (probably it is something impossible), therefore we say "on the floor".

[image]